# Prove that every positive scalar multiple of a positive definite matrix is also positive definite

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, positive-definite

> Prove that if $K$ is any positive definite matrix, then every positive scalar multiple $cK$,
> $c > 0$, is also positive definite.

I feel like there's an easy solution to this but I'm stuck.
I know that if $K$ is a positive definite matrix then there's some form $q(x)=x^\intercal Kx>0$. How could I show that $x^\intercal cKx>0$? Can we just say that since $c>0$ the form $cq(x)$ must also be greater than $0$? I feel like that's not a good enough proof.

Comment: That is a good enough proof.

Comment: Note that $q(x)$ is just a real number. You have $q(x)>0$ and $c>0$, so.....

Comment: Thanks folks! Turns out I was just overthinking this problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes it suffices since $x^TcKx=c(x^TKx)>0$ or equivalently we also have

$$x^T(cK)x=(\sqrt cx^T)K(\sqrt c x)>0$$